# КриптоПро .NET System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, криптопро

Подскажите, может быть кто-то сталкивался со следующей проблемой, или хотя бы просто есть мысли, как с ней быть.

Написана программа с использованием КриптоПро .NET ещё пару лет назад, и с тех пор практически не меняется, всё работает как надо.

Но периодически (ну точнее за все время была пара тройка таких случаев, и все пришлись на последнюю пару-тройку месяцев) спустя какое-то время подписание просто перестает работать, получаем ошибку

```
System.NotSupportedException: Алгоритм ключа сертификата не поддерживается.
в System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey()
```

Со слов пользователя, если ошибка возникла, она продолжает повторяться до закрытия приложения. А вот после перезапуска пропадает.
Как-то принудительно воспроизвести, понять причину или получить дополнительную информацию не удалось.

В самом коде программы никакого кеширования нет, т.е. на каждое подписание идёт поиск по хранилищу и т.д.

```
var storeMy = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
storeMy.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
// тут более сложная логика поиска по разным критериям 
// (по имени, по отпечатку и т.д., смотря что указано пользователем в настройках), 
// оставляю лишь кусок просто для понимания
var certCol = storeMy.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certThumbprint, false);
// ... дальше набор кода по выбору, если несколько сертификатов
var signerCert = ...;
var ct = signerCert.PrivateKey.GetType();
// ОШИБКА ВОЗНИКАЕТ ТУТ^^^
```

Возможно где-то что-то на уровне System.Security.Cryptography или КриптоПРО кешируется и есть возможность принудительно сбросить/очистить что-либо, чтобы обойтись без перезапуска приложения?

Не исключаю, что проблема может быть внешней и пользователи что-то ещё делали помимо перезапуска, когда проблема возникала.

Comment: Вам нужна трассировка стека, которая обычно есть у каждого исключения. По трассировке вы поймете, в каком методе и при каком вызове сбой. Далее с учетом того, что вы теперь знаете источник, оберните его в `try-catch` и выполните восстанавливающий работу приложения код в случае исключения. Попутно можно залогировать всё что возможно.

Comment: @aepot спасибо, но это не то что требуется. Стек трейс понятен и как раз логируется.
Суть в том, что дело не моём коде, точнее не совсем в нем.
Ошибка перехвачена, стек в логе есть, программа работает дальше, на следующей попытке подписания снова та же ошибка, снова перехвачен. И так до бесконечности. Возникла 1 раз и не пропадает, не смотря на то что обработана корректно. Где возникает тоже понятно - обращение к PrivateKey сертификата, а дальше уже внутренности, которые мне недоступны, почему в этот момент у него возникает "Алгоритм ключа сертификата не поддерживается".

Comment: Проблема в самом типе ключа. Судя по исходникам, `NotSupportedException` бросается в том случае, если алгоритм шифрования не является RSA или DSA. Я так понимаю, у вас ECDsa. Попробуйте вместо вызова `PrivateKey` вызвать `GetECDsaPrivateKey`

Comment: @AndreiKhotko это не объясняет периодичность проблемы. Т.е. PrivateKey нормально себе доступен. И лишь иногда спустя какое-то время вылезала такая ошибка. Но опять, натолкнули на мысль, расширю в этой части логирование на всякий случай.

Comment: @Aries разобрались с ошибкой? У нас такая же вылезла, не знаем даже куда копать :(

Comment: @OwDafuq Нет. Ошибка была лишь на одном конкретном рабочем месте. Сейчас его нет, и соответственно ошибки тоже нет.

Comment: @Aries жаль, думал, что хоть вы подскажите как исправить это :(